# Intelligently troubleshooting git ssh definition for a specific remote

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

There's several questions and answers about this, but they don't work for me. I have added in `~/.ssh/config` the following, reflecting my intent of using a specific ssh key for a specific git server:

```
Host HOST-NICKNAME-FOR-THIS-FILE
    Hostname THE-HOST-DOMAIN-NAME
    User THE-GIT-USER-ON-THE-HOST
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_filename_for_this_host_and_host_git_user
    IdentitiesOnly yes
```

But am still getting a password prompt when trying to push the the remote having the `Hostname` defined above (second row of the config snippet). Should I refresh git or ssh in some way to pick up the new config?

Being asked my password upon pushing, I wonder whether this means the git server is trying to authenticate through both a password *and* the public ssh key which I have uploaded to it, or whether the wrong key is being used by git *despite* my definition above. How can I tell what's going on?

For doubt avoidance: I'm being asked for the git password for the remote server, not the ssh key's local passphrase.

Comment: git version is 1.9.1, and would be very great learning how to log which ssh key git is trying to use, to go a little more intelligently about this and similar matters!

Comment: What are the permissions on `~/.ssh/`, `~/.ssh/config`, and `~/.ssh/id_rsa_filename_for_this_host_and_host_git_user`?

Comment: What happens when you `ssh` directly to the server? Do you get a password prompt?

Comment: @Alex028502 anything particular they need to be? all of them are accessible to the OS user that I use.

Comment: @merlin2011 good question! I get the same password prompt.

Comment: Sometimes it doesn't work if they are wrong.  type `ls -la ~/.ssh`  and I'm sure somebody here can tell you if that is the issue.

Comment: I should confirm the git server is otherwise properly working with SSH for other users before posting again here.

Answer (score 1):

try ssh with -v to see all the keys it tries

for example

```
ssh git@github.com -v

ssh HOST-NICKNAME-FOR-THIS-FILE -v
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a permissions problem with your ssh key setup.

On the remote machine, the permissions on `.ssh` must be `700`, on `.ssh/authorized_keys` must be `600`.

```
chmod 700 ~THE-GIT-USER-ON-THE-HOST/.ssh
chmod 600 ~THE-GIT-USER-ON-THE-HOST/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Of course the public key that corresponds to the private key must also be inside the `authorized_keys` file.

Comment: what do you call the remote machine here? do you mean the git server or what?

Comment: @matanster, Yes the git server. The one that you are trying to `ssh` to.

Comment: Locally on my machine, the key files have the same permissions as other keys I already successfully use. I'll confirm beginning of the week that I'm not the only one trying to SSH to that git server, then come back here. I still wonder what is the explicit way of locally logging what SSH key is being attempted beyond the voodoo style guessing..

Comment: @matanster, If other keys work successfully, then that implies that the public key for this one has simply not been added to authorized_keys yet on the remote machine. This is under the assumption that other keys worked *for this particular remote user*.

Comment: for example `ssh git@github.com -v` or `ssh HOST-NICKNAME-FOR-THIS-FILE -v`

Comment: with `ssh -v` I can see "Offering RSA public key: " per key I have under `~/.ssh`, (obviously   `IdentitiesOnly yes` isn't taking effect which might be a sign of something), not just the one that should be used as per my config definition supplied in the original question body. And then `Next authentication method: password`